# Wicket Framework connect in database

Tags: wicket

I am recently new here. I have a problem about Apache Wicket Framework  version 1.6.0 using IDE netbeans 8.0 to Create Login Form and to connect in mysql database .I have many errors please reply on my problem

Answer (score 2):

Wicket is unmanaged UI Framework. There is no way to use Wicket to connect to database.

You have to use any other mean to connect to database.

Here are some steps that might be of use:
1. Learn to access database in Java
[Connect Java to a MySQL database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2839321/connect-java-to-a-mysql-database)
2. Process information obtained from Database
3. Use Apache wicket to display information obtained from database to user. In your case, IF user is authorized then redirect to other page.